# JSF - One vote/comment/rating per IP/User/day/session

Tags: web, rating-system

I have a JSF application where every site visitor (whether it's a registered user or not) can leave multiple comments and rate existing comments (thumbs up/down). I want to limit the comment ratings to one rating per comment per visitor per day. Can you recommend me the best way to do this? Should I try to log the IP address, or the MAC address (if possible), or something else? Should I save the data in my DB or user the cookies (or something else)?
**Relevant tables and fields:**

```
article (id, title, body...)
comment (id, article_id, user_id, text...)
user (id, username...)
// This structure can be changed if needed
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is very generic. And not java and jsf related. You could as well added cookie,  jdbc or whatever. You even ask for something where you doubt it is even possible (mac address). My suggestion is to start experimenting,  searching google in general and if you have specific problems get back here

Comment: @Kukeltje Already searching...